# How to use Request function in a Scrapy Spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from string import join
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.crawl import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from Gfire.items import GfireItem

class GuideSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Gfire"
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/gfire/guides"
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("gfire/guides.*page=")), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="title"]')
        for site in sites:
            item = GFireItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('./a/text()').extract()
            item['guide_url'] = site.select('./a/@href').extract()
            item['guide_url'] = "http://www.example.com" + join(item['guide_url'])
            items.append(item)
        return Request(items[1], callback=self.parse_item2)

    def parse_item2(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        hero = hxs.select("//h3/a/text()").extract()
        return hero
```

Can't get this spider to work. The request function contains items[1] that should be item['guide_url'] but it says me that the parameter has to be str or unicode.
How can I corret this error? And how can I pass to the callback function the items list? Via request.meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `item[1]` is actually an instance of `GFireItem`.

I'm not certain why you are creating these as you only use *one* (the second site in your list of sites), discarding the rest of the list.

That aside, you need to extract the `items[1]['guide_url']` url when creating the `Request`:

```
        return Request(items[1]['guide_url'], callback=self.parse_item2)
```

Comment: To get only the second site, you can use something like `hxs.select('//div[@class="title"][1]')`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="title"]')
    for site in sites:
        item = GFireItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('./a/text()').extract()
        item['guide_url'] = site.select('./a/@href').extract()
        item['guide_url'] = "http://www.example.com" + join(item['guide_url'])
        items.append(item)
    return Request(items[1]['guide_url'], request.meta={'items':items}, callback=self.parse_item2)

def parse_item2(self, response):
    items = response.meta["items"]
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    hero = hxs.select("//h3/a/text()").extract()
    return hero
```

Comment: Maybe you could comment on what your code does differently than the OP's. I couldn't see it immediately by skimming your answer :)